# Enviar email Login e Senha C# windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Vi que tinha como enviar e-mail quando o usuário esquece a senha e montei uns códigos diferentes mas todos deram erros.

Acho que faltou alguma coisa e será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

segue os codigos

```
 if (txtLogin.Text != "")
        {

            UsuarioDTO objUsuDto = new UsuarioDTO();
            objUsuDto.Login = txtLogin.Text;
            objUsuDto = new UsuarioModel().PesquisarUsuarioLogin(objUsuDto);
            emailUsuarioEnvio = objUsuDto.Email;
            login = objUsuDto.Login;
            senha = objUsuDto.Senha;

            if (emailUsuarioEnvio != "")
            {
```

// tentativa n1

```
                //SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.dominio.com.br", 587);
                //smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailEnvio@emailEnvio.com.br","Senha");
                //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                //MailAddress remetente = new MailAddress("remetente@email.com.br");
                //MailAddress destinatario = new MailAddress(emailUsuarioEnvio);


                //MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage(remetente, destinatario);


                //mensagem.Body = "Seu Login é: "+login + "  Sua senha é: "+senha;
                //mensagem.Subject = "Recuperação de Senha do Sistema
                //NetworkCredential credenciais = new NetworkCredential("remetente@email.com.br", "Senha");
                //smtp.Credentials = credenciais;
                //smtp.Send(mensagem);
```

// outra tentativa n2

```
                //System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                //message.To.Add(emailUsuarioEnvio);
                //message.Subject = "Recuperação de senha do sistema de empilhadeira";
                //message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("remetente@email.com.br");
                //message.Body = "\n O seu Login é: " + login + "\n A sua senha é: " + senha;
                //System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.dominio.com.br");
                //smtp.Send(message);
```

// tentativa de n3

```
                SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient("mai.dominio.com.br");
                MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
                Message.From = new MailAddress("remetente@email.com.br");
                Message.To.Add(emailUsuarioEnvio);
                Message.Body = "teste de email";
                Message.Subject = "Seja bem Vindo";
                cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("remetente@email.com.br", "Senha");
                cliente.Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(587);
                cliente.Send(Message);

            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Ficaria algo assim:

```
try
        {
            MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            mensagem.From = new MailAddress("[EMAIL AQUI]", "[NOME AQUI]");
            mensagem.To.Add("[EMAIL AQUI]");
            mensagem.Subject = ("[ASSUNTO AQUI]");
            mensagem.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

            //Configuracao SMTP para HOTMAIL
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("[EMAIL]", "[SENHA]");
            smtp.Send(mensagem);

        }

catch { }
```

Fique atento com as informações que você deve substituir...
Pode ser que haja algumas mudanças na parte de configuração do SMTP dependendo do servidor que você escolher para envio.

Comment: Valeu amigo muito obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Não tem nada de errado com seu último código, só faltou mesmo fazer `Dispose` do `SmtpClient`. Também não é necessário converter o número 587 para inteiro, pois ele já é um inteiro. O código que usei, copiado do seu, e funcionou foi:

```
using (SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient("usuario.dominio.com"))
{
    MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
    Message.From = new MailAddress("usuario@dominio.com");
    Message.To.Add("usuario_2@outrodominio.com.br");
    Message.Body = "teste de email";
    Message.Subject = "Seja bem Vindo";
    cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("usuario@dominio.com", "UMA_SENHA");
    cliente.Port = 587;
    cliente.Send(Message);
}
```

Se todos os dados do servidor SMTP estão realmente corretos (vale a pena verificar se o servidor requer SSL e adicionar `cliente.EnableSsl = true;` se for o caso), a única coisa que poderia estar barrando o envio da sua mensagem seria um Firewall bloqueando a porta 587. Verifique se na sua rede a porta 587 não está bloqueada, pode ser o Firewall do Windows, um roteador ou até mesmo o modem.