# Como enviar um email sem precisar enviar anexo?

Tags: c#, envio-de-email

Olá, estou com uma dúvida: fiz um script de enviar email, mas gostaria que ao enviá-lo o usuário não precisasse necessariamente colocar um anexo (ou seja, deixar o envio do anexo não obrigatório). Como poderia fazer isso?

Segue o script:

```
public void EnviarEmail()
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        //Identificação do destinario
        msg.To.Add(txtPara.Text);
        //Identificação do Email
        msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("meuemail@hotmail.com");
        //assunto do email
        msg.Subject = txtAssunto.Text;
        //Corpo do email
        msg.Body = txtMensagem.Text;
        //Anexo
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment anexo = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtAnexo.Text);
        msg.Attachments.Add(anexo);
        //coloque seu servidor smtp e porta 587 (configuração smtp do gmail)
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        //login do email que vai enviar as mensagens
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("blablabla@outlook.com", "senha");
        smtp.Send(msg);
        MessageBox.Show("Email enviado!");
        txtAnexo.Clear();
        txtAssunto.Clear();
        txtMensagem.Clear();
        txtPara.Clear();     
    }

private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            EnviarEmail();    
    }
```

É isso. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar email Login e Senha C# windows Form](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65703/enviar-email-login-e-senha-c-windows-form)

Comment: O que acontece se você não colocar o `Attachment`? Até onde eu lembro ele não é obrigatório.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

Esse codigo faz uma verificação para saber se algum anexo foi informado, e ele verifica se realmente o arquivo existe para que possa ser enviado, caso essas condições não sejam verdadeiras ele envia o e-mail sem anexo.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAnexo.Text) && File.Exists(txtAnexo.Text))
{
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment anexo = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtAnexo.Text);
    msg.Attachments.Add(anexo);
}
```

Notei que que você não esta usando o using em seu código, ele serve para liberar os objetos da memoria quando eles não estiverem mais sendo usados.

Aqui explica a importância de usar o using: [Qual a utilidade do using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66230/qual-a-utilidade-do-using)

```
    public void EnviarEmail()
    {
        using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
        {
            //Identificação do destinario
            msg.To.Add(txtPara.Text);

            //Identificação do Email
            msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("meuemail@hotmail.com");

            //assunto do email
            msg.Subject = txtAssunto.Text;

            //Corpo do email
            msg.Body = txtMensagem.Text;

            //Anexo - 
            //Verifica se a txtAnexo.Text não é vazio or null e verifica se existe o anexo no caminho informado
            // Se tiver tudo ok ele envia com anexo, se não envia sem anexo
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAnexo.Text) && File.Exists(txtAnexo.Text))
            {
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment anexo = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtAnexo.Text);
                msg.Attachments.Add(anexo);
            }

            //coloque seu servidor smtp e porta 587 (configuração smtp do gmail)
            using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587))
            {
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                //login do email que vai enviar as mensagens
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("blablabla@outlook.com", "senha");
                smtp.Send(msg);

                MessageBox.Show("Email enviado!");

                txtAnexo.Clear();
                txtAssunto.Clear();
                txtMensagem.Clear();
                txtPara.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aqui deu erro no file falando que não faz parte do parâmetro

Comment: Eu fiz o teste aqui passando "C:\MeuAnexo.PNG" no txtAnexo.Text sendo que eu coloquei esse arquivo no meu diretório C. Você também pode chamar um método tipo ValidaAnexoValido(txtAnexo.Text) fazendo sua logica para validar se o anexo deve ser enviado ou não.

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolver aqui! :)

Answer (score 2):

Apenas remova as linhas que você cria e adiciona um anexo à mensagem. Não existe nada que obrigue que um anexo seja adicionado.

```
msg.Body = txtMensagem.Text;

//Anexo
//System.Net.Mail.Attachment anexo = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtAnexo.Text);
//msg.Attachments.Add(anexo);
```

Se você quiser deixar o envio de anexo como opcional, apenas use uma condição

```
if(anexoValido)
{
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment anexo = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtAnexo.Text);
    msg.Attachments.Add(anexo);
}
```